# Passing multiple parameters using single input control in JasperServer

Tags: java, ireport, jasperserver

I have created jasper report in ireport. I am trying to execute it using jasper server. I want to pass two input parameters to report using single Input Control. This input control is a drop down. It has text and Id. I want to pass both id as well as text to report. Is there any way I can achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a report with input parameters you have to pass them through a HashMap. This is where you put any number of values you like and pass them to JasperReport:

```
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("shopName", shopName);
        map.put("month", Integer.parseInt(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString()));
        map.put("Value2", jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex());

        URL reportFileURL = getClass().getResource("../ireports/MyReport.jrxml");
        File reportFile = new File(reportFileURL.toURI());
        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportFile);
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, map, con);
```

Comment: I don't use the JasperReports server yet. Donal has updated the tags after my answer was posted. If you want me to delete the answer delete your comment and i will delete it too.